# How does jQuery's HTMLstring work

Tags: jquery, html

I was playing with jQuery a little and I had an idea, so I decided to give it a try.

```
$('table').append('<thead><tr><th><th><th>');
```

as you can imagine, this produced:

```
table
-thead
--tr
---th
---th
---th
```

I am aware that you can write the following HTML and get the equivalent structure as above:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
      <th>
      <th>
```

I tried to look at the jQuery source[1], and there doesn't seem to be anything to indicate that jQuery does anything special relating to [`htmlString`](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString). Does jQuery simply append the htmlString as a normal string and let the browser do the work, or is there something I'm missing?

If it's the browser that does the work, does this imply that I can expect different behaviour across different browsers?

[1] https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0600a29256be76bd87adb547545bf7219fafb6ee/src/manipulation.js#L41

Comment: You need to look higher in the source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L13-L24

Comment: @RobW Ah, I completely missed that! I just used CTRL+F! :D Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Pro tip: Before pasting the link to source code on Github, press the `y` key. This navigates to the latest commit involving the current file, making it a permalink. Your current link points to the latest revision of the file, which might change in the future.

Comment: @RobW I updated the Q with the correct link! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does jQuery simply append the htmlString as a normal string and let the browser do the work, or is there something I'm missing?

Yes, and yes. :-)

jQuery lets the browser do the work, but it does some things to help with situations that might otherwise be problematic. For instance:

```
var row = $("<tr><td>foo</td></tr>");
```

You can do that in jQuery, and you get back a jQuery object wrapping a row that isn't (yet) in the DOM, which has a cell in it.

Which seems simple enough, but jQuery has to do work to ensure that that HTML string is parsed within the context of a table (because if you try to make the browser parse it within, say, a `div`, there's a problem).

*Edit*: Rob W pointed to [some relevant source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L13-L24) for this:

```
// We have to close these tags to support XHTML (#13200)
wrapMap = {

    // Support: IE 9
    option: [ 1, "<select multiple='multiple'>", "</select>" ],

    thead: [ 1, "<table>", "</table>" ],
    col: [ 2, "<table><colgroup>", "</colgroup></table>" ],
    tr: [ 2, "<table><tbody>", "</tbody></table>" ],
    td: [ 3, "<table><tbody><tr>", "</tr></tbody></table>" ],

    _default: [ 0, "", "" ]
};
```

Code in jQuery's internal `buildFragment` function uses the map above (and objects derived from it) to ensure the HTML is parsed correctly.